Why is it not generally accepted that Tyranids are the strongest, most adaptable race in Warhammer 40K?
Why is it not generally accepted that Tyranids are the strongest, most adaptable race in Warhammer 40K? And since they are the most adaptable, why have they not conquered other races yet?
It seems to me they outnumber and outsmart all the others. What do other races do to defend against them?
I'd like to know it in a way like "rock paper scissors" - Tyranids have X but the humans have Y, etc.

I'm not an expert in Warhammer, but I seem to recall that the Tyranid invasion is only just starting. The vast bulk of their fleet is still in hyperspace travelling towards the Milky Way galaxy. So the simple reason they haven't taken over is because the Tyranids seen are merely scouts and sappers preparing a beachhead.

As far as defence is concerned, they are just as susceptible as anyone else to having their planet glassed, their troops nuked and their space fleets railgunned until they explode

Because Orks exist. WAAAAAGH!

The premise of the question sounds opinion based in my opinion. When I played DOW2 for example, the Tyranids were described as being very fast to adapt to their new threats, aka. already being used to fighting against the Space Marines/Orks/Eldars they just encountered in a mere few days, whereas a human-being would require several generations. They just purposely create creatures that are the most convenient to deal with the current threat.

I don't know much about Tyranids, but I remember reading that encounter with them always came with heavy losses. Planets that fell victims were devoured clean, and even if you manage to push back, the remaining tendrils will escape towards less protected planet to regrow into a new full fledged hive fleet, whereas surviving planets that got infected will show traces of mutated fauna/flora with enhanced aggressiveness (akin to Catachan jungles). The other species may have managed to push back the Tyranids for now. But at what cost? And for how much longer?

Why is it not accepted?  Because that's heresy!  You wouldn't want to sound like a heretic, would you?

Let me first quote Douglas Adams here:

Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.

This is the reason number one: Tyranids are attacking the Milky Way galaxy, which is pretty big, so even if they were absorbing planets without any resistance, it would take them a long, long time. And notice, that they are the new kid on the block, as they have appeared in 745.M41, while the "current date" of the WH40K universe is somewhere in the first 100s of M42. About 300 years is far too short a period to conquer such a huge region, especially since their FTL travelling method is much slower than one used by other races, that have access to Warp or Webways.
Second, there is the resistance: before I'll go to the Imperium, let's first look at other races:

Orks love Tyranids and it seems that both species thrive on the war together: the high losses that Greenskins can inflict produce stronger Boyz (and attract more Orks to the fight from nearby systems), while Tyranids can feed on the quickly reproducing Orks producing more units to be killed etc... The circle continues producing stronger and stronger Waagh and Tyranid Fleets. At least in one case, the Inquisition was forced to help Tyranids before this spiral went out of control.
Eldars and their dark kin can hide either on their Craftworlds or safely in the webway, while sending Tyranids towards heavily defended (by other races) areas (in the "Dawn of War II" game, Eldars are trying to start a Waagh on Imperial world to stop the incoming fleet). Only Exodites are vulnerable, but they are rare.
Necrons are of no interest to Tyranids, although it is not uncommon for the fights to start whenever some stray fleet gets too close to one of the Tomb Worlds. Such combat is almost always a net loss for the Hive Mind, as it cannot absorb the defeated foes.
Chaos is in a similar position as Necrons, as demons provide no nourishment for the Hive Fleet and apparently the presence of Warp can cause something akin to a headache to the Hive Mind.
Tau are... surprisingly resilient to Hive Fleet invasions! While they have no numbers available to other races, their science and natural ingenuity are a serious problem to the Tyranids. Normally, the Fleet would create stronger and more complex units working better and better against the defender forces, but Tau kept changing strategies and weapons faster than Tyranids could adapt.

And then we have the Imperium of Man: with its millions of billions of Guards, not to mention the Space Marines, Knights and Titan legions. What's more, the Imperium is ready to sacrifice whole subsectors to Exterminatus just to slow down and starve the incoming tide of Tyranids. What's more, humans are willing to temporarily ally themselves with other xenos (Blood Angels and Necrons on Gehenna, Imperial Guards and Tau on Ke'lshan).
To sum it up: Tyranids have to fight hard for almost every single planet and there is still a lot of planets to fight for.

The size of the galaxy really is incomprehensible. Estimated at roughly 100,000 light year across and at least 1,000ly thick, with 100 billion stars as the low guess. The human mind just isn't designed to truly grasp the scale of it.

@Xantec so a bit bigger than from here to the pharmacy on the corner, no?

Just be sure to bring your towel with you when you go, and you'll be fine.

@Yasskier you might want to bring AT LEAST 2 or 3 pairs of underwear.

Can't say I exactly agree with the part about the Orks, seeing that in the Octarius War, any boyz the Orks were loosing was more biomass for the Tyranids to produce more bugs. But the conflict did entice more Orks to attend the party by saving strength instead of spending it fighting each others (at least when I last read that wiki page 5 or so years ago). Still, upvoted for the rest.

@Clockwork True, it seems that in the Orks/Tyranid army books, there are stories about how bad things are for one of the sides until an Ork hero/special bioform appears. But I do remember a story (I think it was in the "Deathwatch" series?) about Marines hunting a Warboss only because they were afraid that Greenskins were getting too strong fighting Tyranids. Well, the galaxy is big and full of war.

Couple of typos - Douglas Adams's surname only has one 'd' in it, and "Exdites" should be Exodites. But I don't have enough rep for a 2-character edit to fix these.

This answer is based on oldish lore, so its possible some of this has been retconned since, but it was previously established that the main Tyranid swarm (beyond the galactic edge) was unstoppable but that the present swarms were only dangerous due to how hard they were to detect.
While Tyranids are portrayed as the galaxy's apex predators, they are incapable of ever being anything more than predictable apex predators. For all the incredible adaptions and capabilities for doing the one activity they engage in, they are incapable of innovating beyond that. So if you left the Tyranids and the Tau alone for 10,000 years, the Tau would be a far more advanced and dangerous force while the Tyranids would be no more dangerous than they are currently. At present, and at an incredible biomass cost, the Tyranids can spawn a creature which is the match for two squads of space marines. That is both impressive and scary, but that is the hard limit of Tyranid innovation. They've never done better and will never do better than that. Additionally, while Tyranid ground forces can be mutated to counter any opposing army, fancier Tyranids take more biomass and time to make - and as Tyranids have no supply lines or stockpiles they can call on for re-enforcements, if the Tyranid’s start to lose a conflict, they are near incapable of turning things around as they burn away their remaining bio-mass facing off against the superior force. The odd thing about Warhammer 40k is that the scale of the conflict is so huge that no matter how dangerous, large or advanced your army is, if it becomes enough of a threat, the imperium will eventually muster up a large enough force to crush it – so while your incursion may damage the Imperium as resources are drawn away from other critical areas, no singular faction is capable of toppling the Imperium. So in truth, what makes the Tyranids dangerous is not their biological superiority or their tactics but rather how hard they are to detect or fully eradicate once their main forces are broken.
The funniest part is that the Tyranids are literally incapable of facing off against Necron worlds even if they wanted to. When Necrons gain control of worlds, they turn them into Tomb Worlds – worlds in which all biomatter has been eradicated down to the molecular level. As Tyranids rely on consuming planets worth of biomatter to persist, and Necron Tomb worlds are devoid of biomatter, if the Tyranids expended the biomass required to transverse space from their current location to a Necron Tomb world and then left without even fighting the Necrons, the Tyranids would have suffered a catastrophic loss of biomatter by making the unprofitable journey without even engaging the Necrons.
The sole McGuffin in the Tyranid’s arsenal is the fact that the main Tyranid swarm, currently approaching the galactic rim, is so large that Inquisitorial estimates were that arming every living man, woman and child in the Imperium and diverting them form every other war front wouldn’t be able to do little more then slow the main Tyranid hive down. And even then, that force is at most just a match for the fully awakened Necron empire. The old lore was that the Necron’s won the ancient war in the heavens, but after a galactic plague of very odd mind eating demons, they went into total hibernation so that primitive species could evolve enough to serve as suitable slave races for the Necrons. While the Necron hibernation systems seemed to be suffering extensive glitches in their re-activation protocols during the 41th millennium, in the lore provided for the new edition in the 42nd millenium we were told that the Necron’s had sorted that all out and are now fully awake. So if I were to guess the story direction, we are probably heading towards a galaxy wide conflict between the Necrons and the Tyranids across the heavens while the other factions cower in the shadows beneath. And once the Tyranids lose their overwhelming numbers advantage, the remaining specimens really aren’t that impressive.

Thanks Alot! :D  Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a fairly comprehensive answer, but it would be great if you could give us an idea where in (the vast amounts of) canon these points are drawn from.

Sorry, I'll need to check the site guide lines before responding again. The issue is that the only point I raise here with a proper reference is that Inquisitor's assessment that the entire Imperium could but briefly slow the main hive fleet's advance. That snippet is available as a much tossed about quote on most wh40k wikis. There aren't great reference points for the rest of the arguments due to the offhand natures in which the info tends to appear. Most of the stuff I've mentioned here is from off-hand comments from characters across numerous stories and pc games.

A part of your answer reminds me of something I read about the Octarius War, in which the Imperium managed to get the Orks and the Tyranids into fighting each others. During one of the battles fought, the Orks preemptively shot at the Hive Fleet before it reached the planet. In doing so, they managed to weaken the Tyranids so much that the Orks vastly outnumbered the Tyranids. And so, instead of using sheer overwhelming numbers, they relied on hit-and-run tactics, until they took out all the Orks and replenished their forces https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Octarius_War#Ghorala

Yeah. There are nuances and different outcomes based on the situation and the author. There is a similar point made in a recent book where a Tyranid fleet attacked the Blood Angels homeworld. The Tyranids fleets are incredibly vulnerable in space as organic space vessels navigating via farts can't compete with warp-core powered space ships. I've seen instances where it was stated that if the main Tyranid fleet ships (and the norn queens) were destroyed in space, the fleets tended to shatter into small feral swarms. I listened to those three books on youtube though. No idea how I'd quote them:P

It reminds me of the plot of DOW II. At the very end, after we are done poisoning the main hive fleet (and thus supposedly killing the hive mind), the ship as a whole breaks down into smaller tendrils or something. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H90c_OLwXIg

Thats how most Tyranid incursions tend to go. A new hive fleet will appear above or below the galactic disk, will inflict untold destruct before it is discovered and a large enough force is mustered to smash it and then the Imperium will will have to dedicate fleets or chapters to endlessly chase down the splinter fleets of the larger fleet that was just smashed. So the most dangerous aspect of the Tyranids is that once you get an infestation you seldom ever eradicate it completely and have to dedicate permanent resources to keeping it in check lest any splinter fleet manage to fully recover.
